# jQuery ui datepicker - show only months that exist in the dates range

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a range of dates that i show in multiple calendars!
i want to show only month calendars that exist among the dates range i have!
Is there anyway i can do this! or at least to start from the first existing month instead of the current month?

**my code:**

```
$.getJSON($controller + 'method' ,{param:param}, function(data){
            var dates = data.dates;
            var startDate = data.startDate;
            var numberOfMonths = data.numberOfMonths;

            $element.datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                    if (times.indexOf(string) != -1){
                        return [true, 'highlighted', 'date'];
                    }
                    else{
                        return [true, '', ''];
                    }
                },
                showCurrentAtPos:1,
                current: new Date(startDate),
                showWeek: true,
                format: 'Y-m-d',
                numberOfMonths: numberOfMonths,
                minDate:-1,
                maxDate:-2
            }).attr('readonly','readonly');
        })
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = new Date(); //Your start date goes here
var endDate = new Date(); //Your end date goes here

$element.datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        if (times.indexOf(string) != -1) {
            return [true, 'highlighted', 'date'];
        } else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    },
    showCurrentAtPos: 1,
    current: new Date(startDate),
    showWeek: true,
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    numberOfMonths: numberOfMonths,
    minDate: startDate,
    maxDate: endDate
    }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i used negative values for minDate,maxDate so calendars won't be selectable! i got the months the way you provided but now calendars are activated again!